# How to make couchbase service auto start if server reboots?

Tags: linux, shell, automation, couchbase

Our on premise servers use RHEL 6.5 and sometimes a node reboots on its own. This makes couchbase service killed on that node and this causes severe outage at applicaiton side. 
How can we make couchbase service to restart automatically if a node reboots?

Comment: Is there not a systemd service and so "systemctl enable <Servicename>">

Comment: If your server is rebooting "on its own", you have bigger problems than starting couchbase.

Comment: @Flimzy - We have taken that node out of cluster since it had issues . But , to automate the process of starting couchbase service in case it goes down, we need to have an auto restart mechanism in place.

Comment: @RamanSailopal - We don't have this utility on our servers . Any other suggestion ?

Comment: Restarting services automatically is good. But this question is entirely off-topic for SO. Try ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have chkconfig, as seen [here](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1455613). Write a proper init script for LSB scripts and add it to running runlevel, see [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL:SysVInitScript).
You can just add the command to /etc/rc.d/rc.local to run at boot, see [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot).